# vertica - string octets length

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, vertica

I has such query and such error:

```
dbadmin=> update platforms set description = E'Ð®Ð»Ñ\217 - Ð\237ÐµÑ\200Ñ\203, Ð\221Ð¾Ð»Ð¸Ð²Ð¸Ñ\217, Ð­ÐºÐ²Ð°Ð´Ð¾Ñ\200 where id = 189;
ERROR 4800:  String of 92 octets is too long for type Varchar(80)
```

When I try to check length of sting, I got another value:

```
dbadmin=> select octet_length(E'Ð®Ð»Ñ\217 - Ð\237ÐµÑ\200Ñ\203, Ð\221Ð¾Ð»Ð¸Ð²Ð¸Ñ\217, Ð­ÐºÐ²Ð°Ð´Ð¾Ñ\200');
 octet_length 
--------------
           84
(1 row)
```

Why does the value is different?

And how can I automatically cut string to particular octets number? 
Currently I'm using python function, and it returns string with length 80 (the string above), there are some `sqlalchemy` classes:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import String
from project import SessionVertica

def process(max_length, value):
    literal_processor = String.literal_processor(SessionVertica.bind.dialect)
    if literal_processor:
        result = unicode(literal_processor(value))
    else:
        result = unicode(value)
    if len(result) >= max_length:
        result = result[:max_length - 2] + '\''
    return 'E' + result
```

Answer (score 0):

easy :)

```
def process(max_length, value):
    literal_processor = String.literal_processor(SessionVertica.bind.dialect)
    if literal_processor:
        result = unicode(literal_processor(value))
    else:
        result = unicode(value)
    return result + '::varchar({length})'.format(length=max_length)
```